# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in Xcode

Tags: xcode, nsstring, uiimageview, uiimage, tesseract

I really need you guy HELP , I run my program in Xcode and its successful but later,

Its show me this error: ****Thread 1: Program received signal :"EXC_BAD_ACCESS"** on my program line that I have ****bold below** :

```
- (NSString *) ocrImage: (UIImage *) uiImage
{
    CGSize imageSize = [uiImage size];
    double bytes_per_line   = CGImageGetBytesPerRow([uiImage CGImage]);
    double bytes_per_pixel  = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel([uiImage CGImage]) / 8.0;

    CFDataRef data = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider([uiImage CGImage]));
    const UInt8 *imageData = CFDataGetBytePtr(data);

    // this could take a while. maybe needs to happen asynchronously.

    **char* text = tess->TesseractRect(imageData,(int)bytes_per_pixel,(int)bytes_per_line, 0, 0,(int) imageSize.height,(int) imageSize.width);**

    // Do something useful with the text!
    NSLog(@"Converted text: %@",[NSString stringWithCString:text encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    return [NSString stringWithCString:text encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Thank you guy .

Comment: Can you post the code where `tess` is set?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that `imageData` is not NULL here. That's the most common cause of what you're seeing. You should reconsider your title to something more related to your problem, and focus on the stacktrace and all the variables you are passing to `TesseractRect()`.

The other major likelihood is that `tess` (whatever that is) is a bad pointer, or that is not part of the correct C++ class (I assume this is Objective-C++; you're not clear on any of that).

Comment: Do you have an example of the check for image data being null I've tried imageData == NULL imageData == [NSNull Null] imageData == nil nothing works.  I can't find a way to stop this crash from occurring.

Comment: `imageData==NULL` is the test for it being NULL. If it's not NULL, then this is not your problem. I said it's the most common cause of this kind of crash, not that it's the certain cause. As I noted, it is also possible that `tess` is an invalid pointer. It's unclear where `tess` comes from. If your memory management is sloppy; then you should spend time cleaning it up. The best single way to avoid sloppy memory management is to use accessor methods for your ivars. Also, it's unclear where you're calling CFRelease(data). Are you?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *)readAndProcessImage:(UIImage *)uiImage
{
  CGSize imageSize = [uiImage size];
  int bytes_per_line = (int)CGImageGetBytesPerRow([uiImage CGImage]);
  int bytes_per_pixel = (int)CGImageGetBitsPerPixel([uiImage CGImage]) / 8.0;

  CFDataRef data =
      CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider([uiImage CGImage]));
  const UInt8 *imageData = CFDataGetBytePtr(data);

  // this could take a while. maybe needs to happen asynchronously?
  char *text = tess.TesseractRect(imageData, bytes_per_pixel, bytes_per_line, 0,
                                  0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);

  NSString *textStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:text];

  delete[] text;
  CFRelease(data);
  return textStr;
}
```